# Add a vertical tab as delimiter for output text on XSL

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I am trying to parse an XML file for converting into text through XSL.

I have the requirement that the output should have vertical tab as delimiter between columns.

How I can write the vertical tab as delimiter on XSL.

I tried using

```
xsl:value-of select="concat(NAME,VT,CLASS......
```

But I am getting error

> An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0xb) was found in the value of attribute "select" and element is "xsl:value-of".

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XSLT styesheet must also be a well-formed XML document. The vertical tab character is not allowed in an XML 1.0 document, but it is allowed in XML 1.1. Try declaring your stylesheet as XML 1.1 by including:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

at the very beginning, then use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="concat(NAME, '&#x0B;', CLASS)"/>
```

This may not work with all XSLT processors, but it does work with Xalan and Saxon.

Answer (score -2):

How about this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="NAME"/>&#x0B;<xsl:value-of select="CLASS"/>
```

Comment: What difference does this make?

Comment: It's not in an attribute

Comment: What difference does that make? You will still get the same error. Compare: http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEva with: http://xsltransform.net/3NSSEva/1

Comment: Spite downvoting my answer will not make your answer any more valuable.

Comment: Thanks It worked xml version="1.1" is really critical part